# SQLite assembly in separate project

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate, assembly-resolution

I have 2 projects (in question)

```
DataAccessLayer
Tests
```

I am using Fluent nHibernate, and setting up a SQLite database.

I have referenced `System.Data.SQLite` in `DataAccessLayer` project (with `CopyLocal = true`) but when I run the configuration in the `Tests` project, nHibernate cannot find the SQLite provider assembly.

Now I have added the SQLite reference to `Tests` project and it runs without a problem.

But I would like to leave the assembly reference in my `DataAccessLayer` project, as that is where there the data access layer (what database to use) is.

Why does my `Tests` project not see the SQLite assembly reference from the `DataAccessLayer` project?

`DataAccessLayer` is referenced in `Tests` project.

**Edit** - Connection String in app.config

```
  <connectionStrings>        
    <add name="SQLiteLocal" connectionString="Data Source=SQLite.db;" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Edit** - Exception

```
  ----> NHibernate.HibernateException : Could not create the driver from 
        NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver, NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000,
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4.
  ----> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown 
        by the target of an invocation.
  ----> System.ArgumentException : Unable to find the requested .Net Framework 
        Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

Comment: How is your connection string?

Comment: I had similar problem. Try with `Data Source=|DataDirectory|SQLite.db;version=3`.

Comment: Still Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver, NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4.